# Query on 64bit porting of C/C++ code

Tags: c++, windows, 32bit-64bit

After compiling the code with Visual studio 2008 64 bit compiler for an existing 32 bit app.exe(enterprise app) without using `/Wp64` compilation switch, we resolved all the Level 1/2/3 warnings that we encountered with proper datatype changes and then ran the application with `AllocationPreference` registry key set.

Application crashes with registry key set, and application runs fine, if this registry key is removed.

How do i approach in this situation? Do you think using `/Wp64` will add any value?

Comment: @bk1e i saw your answers for such similar query. Does it make sense  to still add `/Wp64` switch as per above situation?

Comment: `/Wp64` will not catch all portability issues. You will need to debug your program to see what other issues remain.

Comment: @RaymondChen yes we see lot of crash dumps. Do you think covering level 1/2/3 warnings should cover most(80-90%) of the portability issues? like bit-alignments in a structure/union etc..

Comment: Try 64-diagnostics from PVS-Studio tool ( http://www.viva64.com/en/viva64-tool/ ).

Comment: @AndreyCpp Without using this registry key, if i monitor the 'Virtual memory used space' of my app, it shows as `10 GB`, so that means app was taking care of 64 bt address locations. am not sure, How this registry key has selected the higher range addresses on 64 bit virtual address space, that the app fails. Solving every crash takes time.

Comment: `/Wp64` is deprecated and silly. Just compile with a 64-bit compiler and you'll get a much better result. Microsoft also [recommends using `/W4`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yt4xw8fh.aspx) to catch more portability issues. Keep an eye out for pointer-to-int conversions, which may contain a cast hiding the fact you're actually doing something wrong. If you can, also try using a more strict compiler like GCC (see [MinGW-w64](http://mingw-w64.sourceforge.net/)), which will catch a lot more issues if you enable its warnings.

Comment: @rubenvb: The two suggestions are not orthogonal, `/Wp64` alwo works for 64 bits builds.

Comment: @MSalters from the page I linked in my previous comment: "If you regularly compile your application by using a 64-bit compiler, you can just disable /Wp64 in your 32-bit compilations because the 64-bit compiler will detect all issues." `/Wp64` is deprecated, and superceded by the 64-bit compiler. The thing is, the compiler can't prevent you from shooting yourself in the foot at any warning level.

Answer (score 3):

You approach this problem by looking at the line of code which crashes. Pretty much like you'd approach any other crash, really. "Solving every crash takes time" you say. Well, each crash is a bug. Think about what that says about your application. How many of the bugs cause crashes, how many corrupt data silently?

`/Wp64` isn't a bad idea, on 64 bits builds. But getting your code base in order is more important.

Comment: combination of `/Wp64 /W3` switch actually helped me provide Level 1 warnings now.